# Java stream filter items of specific index

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for a concise way to filter out items in a List at a particular index. My example input looks like this:

```
List<Double> originalList = Arrays.asList(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0);
List<Integer> filterIndexes = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);
```

I want to filter out items at index `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`. I have a for loop that skips items that match the index but I was hoping there would be an easy way of doing it using streams. The final result would look like that:

```
List<Double> filteredList = Arrays.asList(0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 10.0);
```

Comment: This is incredibly easy using a `for` loop and `remove(int)`. Don't use streams for everything.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBoddington. Coming from .NET work, I'm used to using LINQ for most of the array/list operations and its easy to do this using LINQ so was hoping something similar would be in Java 8 streams

Comment: Streams and _any_ kind of indexing don't get along well at all.

Comment: These explicit array creation statements like `new Double[] {…}` and `new Integer[] {…}` are obsolete. Just use, e.g. `List<Integer> filterIndexes = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);`

Comment: @PaulBoddington I posted an answer using **both**, `remove(int)` and *streams*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can generate an `IntStream` to mimic the indices of the original list, then remove the ones that are in the `filteredIndexes` list and then map those indices to their corresponding element in the list (a better way would be to have a `HashSet<Integer>` for indices since they are unique by definition so that `contains` is a constant time operation).

```
List<Double> filteredList = 
    IntStream.range(0, originalList.size())
             .filter(i -> !filterIndexes.contains(i))
             .mapToObj(originalList::get)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

If your `filteredIndexes` list is presorted, you can avoid checking every element in this way:

```
List<Double> filteredList = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, filterIndexes.size())
    .mapToObj(idxPos -> idxPos == 0 
           ? originalList.subList(0, filterIndexes.get(idxPos)) 
           : idxPos == filterIndexes.size() 
           ? originalList.subList(filterIndexes.get(idxPos-1)+1, originalList.size()) 
           : originalList.subList(filterIndexes.get(idxPos-1)+1, filterIndexes.get(idxPos)))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here we create a number of sublists which contain all the elements between the filtered indices, then just flatten them into the single final list. For big input (e.g. a million of numbers) this solution could be magnitudes faster than one proposed by @AlexisC.

Answer (score 2):

If you sort your indexes **descending**, then you can use `java.util.List.remove(int)` to remove the items.

```
List<Double> originalList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0));
List<Integer> filterIndexes = Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8);

filterIndexes.stream()

    // remove higher indixes first, because each remove affects all indexes to the right
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())

    // make sure to use remove(int) not remove(Object) in java.util.List to use indexes
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)

    // remove each index
    .forEach(originalList::remove);

// print results
originalList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Don’t use `.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)`. That works, but you are converting the `Integer` object to an `int` value to pass it to `Integer valueOf(int)` to get again an `Integer` object which is then auto-unboxed to an `int` as you are using `mapToInt`. You surely want either, `.mapToInt(i->i)` or `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`, performing a single unboxing, instead.

Comment: @Holger Thanks! `Integer::intValue` what was I was looking for. I also tried `Function.identity()` but that did not work.

Comment: Yes, `Function.identity()` returns a `Function` rather than a `ToIntFunction`, so that doesn’t work as the conventional type compatibility rules apply here, rather than functional signature matching as when using `x -> x` directly…

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use simple `Iterator`?

```java
Stream<Integer> rows = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
Iterator<Integer> it = rows.iterator();
int pos = 0;

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Integer num = it.next();

    if (pos++ == 0) {
        // this is a head
    } else {
        // this is a record
    }
}
```