# Concurrent List Modification Using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code snippet.

```
List<String> list = ArrayUtils.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
List<Integer> indices = ArrayUtils.asList(1, 3, 4);
indices.stream().map(list::get).forEach(list::remove);
```

When I run this code I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 3
```

which is to be expected, because Java 8 streams are lazy.

I could built in a reduction operation like `.collect(...)` before the `forEach`, but I just asked myself if there is a more elegant way to do this, or if I shouldn't use streams in such cases.

Edit: `ArrayUtils.asList(...)` mimics `Arrays.asList(...)`, but returns a mutable list.

Comment: By the way, you can simply remove items from a list by index.

Comment: @biziclop I know. My rationale was that the indices of specific list elements change while modifying the list.

Comment: The changes here between your `ArrayUtils` and the standard `Arrays.asList` are significant. I assume that your utility returns a new list that is _not fixed-sized_, contrary to the built-in. Otherwise your code would throw a different exception, mainly `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Apparently, `ArrayUtil.asList` returns a list supporting `remove` operations (most likely an `ArrayList`). That’s the problem with non-standard functions, the reader doesn’t know. So you need `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));` to do the same with the standard API.

Comment: The problem with changing indices can be circumvented by processing from highest index to lowest and avoiding duplicates, e.g. `indices.stream() .distinct() .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) .forEach(ix -> list.remove((int)ix));`

Comment: @Holger The method just returns a (mutable) ArrayList. I looked as Arrays.asList and it seems to do the same...

Comment: I posted an answer in the duplicated question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37321077/476791 (I just saw, that @Holger has already posted a similar solution as comment here)

Comment: @Alex: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792194/2711488)

Comment: Ups, that is another `ArrayList` there, sorry. I will edit it back and add a comment (though the question is indeed a duplicate, I will leave it at that.)

Comment: @Holger This is also potentially a lot faster, if we're talking about `ArrayList`s.