# How to remove First element based on condition using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine that I have this list of integers

```
List<Integer> myList= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,4);
```

Now I want to sum this elements excluding the first max value:

```
int sumExcludeMax = myList.stream()
            .filter(x -> x != Collections.max(list))
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .sum();
```

In this way it's excluding all 4 in the list. How can I exclude just the first one using for instance `.findFirst()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java stream filter items of specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294051/java-stream-filter-items-of-specific-index)

Comment: No, I just want to exclude the first one.

Comment: You'll be better off writing non-stream code for that. Your logic of "all elements except one instance of the max element" does not translate easily into streams. You could avoid the sorting of ernest_k's answer too (although that might not matter for small lists, it's still unnecessary sorting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `sort` in reverse order, then skip one element:

```
int result = myList.stream()
               .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
               .skip(1)
               .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
               .sum();
```

If you're on Java 12+, you can use `Collectors.teeing` in a different approach, computing the max in the first downstream, the sum in the second, and then the difference to work out the result:

```
int result = myList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                   Collectors.maxBy(Integer::compare),
                   Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue), 
                   (v1, v2) -> v2 - v1.orElse(0)));
```

Both of these options yield `10`.

Comment: Yes, that was the perfect solution following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294051/java-stream-filter-items-of-specific-index that you provided. Thanks

Comment: In the final application of the two streams, `Integer.valueOf(...)` is not required.

Comment: @WJS Correct... I put it in when I had some compiler errors, then forgot to remove it.

Comment: I especially like your first solution.  I didn't consider that one.

Comment: @WJS Thanks. I think it might be slower than the second one, or than NoDataFound's solution based on summary statistics.

Answer (score 4):

You should not invoke `max` each time: `Collections.max(myList)` is evaluated for each item in `myList` while the list is not mutating (I assumed that you computed the max of the same list and that `Collection.max(list)` was a typo):

And for your question, if you want to sum all but the first max, then I think this works:

```
int sumExcludeMax = myList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()
                  - Collections.max(myList);
```

- Sum of 1,2,3,4,4 is: 14.
- Max is 4, removing it once make it 10.

Since you are computing a `IntStream`, you can also summarize (I'm using Java 11 here, but it works with 8 apart from the `var` stuff):

```
var ss = myList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
long result = ss.sum() - ss.max();
```

Comment: I suppose the max number might be more often in there than twice.

Comment: The OP is about "filtering the first one for instance", first one referring to the first of numbers being the max. So I think my answer works given these postulate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.distinct()` in the stream object then you only get the max once, but also every other number only once, if you need the other numbers as duplicates it gets a bit more complicated.

```
List<Integer> myList= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,4);
int sumExcludeMax = myList.stream().distinct()
   .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
   .sum();
```

This works if you need the other dublicates:

```
List<Integer> myList= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,4);
int sumExcludeMax = myList.stream()
      .filter(x -> x != Collections.max(myList))
      .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
      .sum() + Collections.max(myList);
```

Comment: What happens if I have : List<Integer> myList= Arrays.asList(1,3,3,4,4); Then the sum will be just 1+2+3+4, instead of 1+2+3+3+4

Comment: Yes, do you need the three two times? Because If you do I will modify it.